# Uploading/importing a .csv in Hue - specifying the correct delimiter, etc

Tags: csv, hadoop, delimiter, hue

I am attempting to upload an interesting dataset that I found on Kaggle.com/datasets contained in a folder called "Questions from Cross Validated Stack Exchange" (specifically the file "Questions.csv" found here: https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/statsquestions)  to Cloudera's Hue so that I can use Hive to query the data.

**However, I'm having trouble choosing the delimiter to uploading the .csv correctly.  I don't see a place to select a text qualifier, escape character, etc.**

I'm on an Oracle VirtualBox VM Linux box which I downloaded from: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

I'm using the Cloudera distribution of Hadoop to access Hue: https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-8.html  I'm specifically using the Metastore Manager on Hue to attempt to upload the Questions.csv data file.

Any assistance for uploading/importing a .csv like this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: _"I'm using the Cloudera distribution of Hadoop to access Hue"_ >> that's the other way around! Hue is a (half-decent) UI for Hadoop. It can be used to upload a CSV file into HDFS *(unless it's silently truncated after the fist 128 MB block limit)*, to map a Hive "EXTERNAL" table on the file, to query the table in SQL, etc. But for each individual task you can find a better tool.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter 

Okay...what other tool would you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

You can first create a table with this kind of parameters :

```
CREATE TABLE databaseXX.tableXX (column1 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

More details on Hive table creation in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable

Then, you will have to upload the csv file in a hdfs folder and use :

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/tmp/myCsvFile' 
 OVERWRITE INTO TABLE databaseXX.tableXX;
```

I find it the easiest way to transform a csv file into a table using Hue.